# How to send a list of objects in soap request with django?

Tags: python, django, soap

I want to send a request containinga list of objects to soap, using django;

i tried as below:

```
data = [{"title": "title1", "pic": "pic1"},
        {"title": "title2", "pic": "pic2"},
         ....
       ]


wsdl = 'http://test.com/Test/TEST.asmx?wsdl'
            tac_data = {
                'user': {'UserName': 'username', 'Pass': 'password'},
                'request': f"""{data}"""
            }

            client = Client(wsdl=wsdl)
            response = client.service.AddDocLossFile(**tac_data)
```

but I gut the following error:

```
'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type \'ViewModels.Dto.DocLossFile\' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.\nPath \'\', line 1, position 1.'
```

does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that the service expects a `JSON object`, but you're providing a `JSON array`.
You need to create `JSON object`.

```
data = [{"title": "title1", "pic": "pic1"},
        {"title": "title2", "pic": "pic2"},
        #...
       ]

# Convert list of dictionaries to a dictionary of dictionaries
data_dict = {f"item{i}": item for i, item in enumerate(data)}

wsdl = 'http://test.com/Test/TEST.asmx?wsdl'
tac_data = {
    'user': {'UserName': 'username', 'Pass': 'password'},
    'request': data_dict
}

client = Client(wsdl=wsdl)
response = client.service.AddDocLossFile(**tac_data)
```

`data_dict` will return you this object:

```
{
    'item0': {'title': 'title1', 'pic': 'pic1'},
    'item1': {'title': 'title2', 'pic': 'pic2'},
    # ...
}
```

Comment: Tankfull... i also want to use this solution; but i want to send the request in a way without using new keys.

Answer (score 0):

your error says SOAP service is expecting a JSON object but is receiving a JSON array instead.

```
data = {
    'title': 'example_title',
    'pic': 'example_pic'
}

# Build the SOAP request payload
tac_data = {
    'user': {'UserName': 'username', 'Pass': 'password'},
    'request': data
}

# Send the SOAP request
client = Client(wsdl=wsdl)
response = client.service.AddDocLossFile(**tac_data)
```

you can Use the suds library to create a SOAP client and send the SOAP request with the serialized data and use the django.core.serializers module to serialize the list of objects into XML format.

```
serialized_data = serialize('xml', data)

# Create a SOAP client and send the request
client = Client('http://test.com/Test/TEST.asmx?wsdl')
response = client.service.my_method(serialized_data)
```

Comment: tanks.... but in this format, how can I send username and password?!

Comment: Create a suds client with the username and password : `client = Client(url, username=username, password=password)` and serialize the data : `serialized_data = client.service.my_method()` then  send the SOAP request : `response = client.service.my_method(serialized_data)`